# Editing FASTA: How to change the headers of FASTA using regex and list, and replace file

Tags: python, regex, list, loops, fasta

I have a FASTA that looks like this:

> '>NZ_UARI01000011.1 Cronobacter sakazakii strain NCTC11467, whole genome shotgun sequence
>   GCGCATTTCTTATTACGGAGAAATACAGCAGCGTGTCTGTTTCAATTTTCAGCTTGTTCCGGATTGTTAAAGAGCAAATA
>   CTT...
>
> '>NZ_UARI01000001.1 Cronobacter sakazakii strain NCTC11467, whole genome shotgun sequence
>   CAATTTTACTTGTTGATATAACAATCACGCTAACTATTCAGCCAATAGCTCCCGCATTAAAACCAGCTACTTCAGCCAAA
>   ...

And I want to change the headers to this:

> '>Cronobacter sakazakii strain NCTC11467_1
>   GCGCATTTCTTATTACGGAGAAATACAGCAGCGTGTCTGTTTCAATTTTCAGCTTGTTCCGGATTGTTAAAGAGCAAATA
>   CTT...
>   '>Cronobacter sakazakii strain NCTC11467_2
>   CAATTTTACTTGTTGATATAACAATCACGCTAACTATTCAGCCAATAGCTCCCGCATTAAAACCAGCTACTTCAGCCAAA
>   ...
>   (and so on)
>   (Ignore the ' in the beginning of the header)

And then I would like to save this file with the name of the header. Ideally I would not like to make a new fasta, but just replace the file with correctionss: 
Cronobacter_sakazakii_strain NCTC11467.fasta

Now this would be easy to do individually but I have over 600 files. So the idea of doing each individual is not a route I would like to take. I have written a script here where I isolate the section of the header I want using regex and store it in a list called new_new. I then want to match up these values and replace with every line that starts with a '>', and then add _1/2/3/... or a # subsequently (as shown above). 
Can you help me with this task?
If the script I provided is not worth continuing, and you have a better solution please let me know.

```
#usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import re
import csv
#sys.argv[1] =fasta 
#sys.argv[2] = list of header names (mass) 
#Gather existing headers to list (new_new)
with open(sys.argv[1], "r+") as text_file:
    lines = text_file.readlines()[1:]
    mylist = []
    new_new = []
    for i in lines:
        if '.' in i:
            mylist.append(i)
    pattern = r">*Cronobacter +\w* +\w* +.*[,]" 
    regex = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
    for j in mylist: 
        for match in regex.finditer(j): 
            value = match.group(0)
            new_new.append(value)
            for k in lines: 
                if '>' in k:
                    k= k.replace('.*',new_new[value])
text_file.close()
'''
```

Comment: Are you sure your input files are correct? They don't look like proper fasta files

Comment: yes. There should be a carat before the NZ name, but yes, just regular FASTA